# libreoffice Calc run a calculation on a part of a range

Tags: sql, range, spreadsheet, libreoffice

I have data about 3 columns in my LibreOffice Calc sheet: **who, where, when**.

I want to make statistics about the when dates. something like a SUM.IF to filter people, but not a SUM. i want to get STDEV on dates but only for one people at a time.
**how could i set a dynamic filter for a range, or a query? but not a view filter.**

something like a `SELECT dates in MyRange WHERE who='abrasive guy'` in SQL, but working in LibreOffice Calc.
so that i would have a table presenting for each of the thousand people a standard derivation of presence.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a pivot table. Assuming you have "who" and "when" columns (A and B), and let's say 4 rows (header, Alice, Bob, Bob):

- select A1:B4
- data -> pivot table -> create
- current selection -> ok
- drag "who" to the row fields
- drag "when" to the data fields
- drag "data" out of column fields e.g. to "available fields"
- double click on "sum - when": select stdev -> ok
- ok to close the "pivot table layout" dialog

The new sheet should contain something close to what you need: stdev, grouped by "who".

Comment: that looks a nice way to do it, but the stdev on dates is not correctly formatted, it should be a number and it formats as a date at each refresh. and i cannot find a way to sort the pivot table by STDEV (sorry i am a noob in pivot tables)

Comment: For sorting: when the cell cursor is inside the pivot table, context menu -> edit layout -> double-click on the "who" row field, options -> sort by, and there you have a list box to decide what is the sorting key and if it has to be asc or desc.

For formatting: what about adding a "when-number" column to your original data where each cell refers to the original date, but you set the cell formatting to a number? And you work with *that* column in the pivot table, then. (That number is in days, you can multiply if you want hours, etc.)